# At the bottom of the Android device are three buttons

Tags: android, fragment

at the bottom of the Android device are three buttons. 
Left an arrow, in the middle  a house and right a square.

How can I use these keys in code?
Thanks

Comment: you mean back button,home button and option button

Answer (score 2):

For Home button (also you cannot override home button gingerbread onwards):

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
doStuff();
     }
```

for Back Button :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  doStuff();
}
```

dont know about square button.

Comment: square bottom is recently used and can't be overridden.Also Onstop() is not for overridding Home button. Rather you cannot override home button gingerbread onwareds